# Processing ArrayList of Objects function does not exist

Tags: arraylist, processing

```
class Measurement {
  int time;
  float value;

  Measurement(int argTime, float argValue) {
    time = argTime;
    value = argValue;
  }
}

ArrayList measurements;

void setup() {
  measurements = new ArrayList();

  measurements.append(new Measurement(1, 20)); 
}
```

Gives me this error:

`The function append(sketch_140628b.Measurement) does not exist`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class ArrayList has no such method as 'append'. The function you want is 'add'.

Comment: That did it, I confused the `ArrayList` with `IntList`, thanks!